# How to Deploy Multiple Django Apps on Single server using Ngnix & GUnicorn?

Tags: django, nginx, deployment, gunicorn, wsgi

I am trying to Deploy Two Django apps with single AWS EC2 Instance having same IP.
But it always failed when I have added the second App.sock and test Supervisor.
I fond some body asked similar question before. but Not answered properly, and my use case is little different. ( [Run multiple django project with nginx and gunicorn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54375834/run-multiple-django-project-with-nginx-and-gunicorn) )

I have followed these steps:
.

- Cloned my project from Git *

  pip install -r requiernments.txt

  pip3 install gunicorn

  sudo apt-get install nginx  -y

  sudo apt-get install  supervisor -y

  cd /etc/supervisor/conf.d

  sudo touch testapp2.conf

  sudo nano testapp2.conf

  ## Updated config file same as below

  [program:gunicorn]

  directory=/home/ubuntu/projects/testapp2/testerapp
  command=/home/ubuntu/projects/testapp2/venv/bin/gunicorn --workers 3 --bind unix:/home/ubuntu/projects/testapp2/testerapp/app.sock testerapp.wsgi:application
  autostart=true
  autorestart=true
  stderr_logfile=/home/ubuntu/projects/testapp2/log/gunicorn.err.log
  stdout_logfile=/home/ubuntu/projects/testapp2/log/gunicorn.out.log

  [group:guni]

  programs:gunicorn

  *----------

  ```
    sudo supervisorctl reread

    sudo supervisorctl update

    sudo supervisorctl status
  ```
- The below steps will work and Site available on browser if there is only One configuration above. But when i have added an additional configuration, it shows 502 Bad Gateway on the Browser. Please help me to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can add one more config file in supervisor conf.d and use different port numbers in the different Django apps.

Comment: I have done like that, but when i have added a second port, the first site is not displaying.
It shows 500 Internal Server Error. can you please tell me the full steps should i followed. ?